# Blackberry Q10 to Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: samsung, blackberry

Want to get my contacts from Blackberry Q10 to Samsung Galaxy S6.

Tried MobileTrans, Dr. Fone (neither support Blackberry anymore) and even tried to use Samsung Switch software.  Neither worked.  What can I do ?  I just want to import the contacts over ..

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options:
**1: Transfer to a Google Account** login to a Google account on your Blackberry and go to the `contacts app > gear icon > General > Contacts Management > Copy Contacts` and you will be able to copy them straight to the Google account. Then login on your Galaxy S6 and enable contacts sync.

**2: Export as a vCard or .vcf file** `contacts app > gear icon > General > Contacts Management > Import/export` and select an option. Then transfer the file from your Blackberry to your S6, and go into the contacts app and click import.

If in option one, for whatever reason you are not able to login to a Google account and transfer the contacts, you can export them as a vCard or .vcf, and import them into Google contacts on your PC directly.

Comment: Thanks, I got it somehow to copy to my SIM card - but then it didnt copy everything so I had to add some manually.  Just strange - but it got like 80% of them.  Then new phone detected them off SIM card.